# jQuery clear all classes and ids except some

Tags: jquery

I am stripping all classes and ids of a div including its children by :

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').find("*")
    .removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').end();
```

but there is a problem, The above code clear every classes and ids.

but I want to keep some classes like:

```
icon-* //i.e. icon-home icon-facebook
active
```

please help me

Comment: I think you will need to perform an each over the items as it looks like you will have a list of classes not to remove.

Comment: If an element has classes `active` and `other_class`, do you want it to skip it or remove `other_class` and leave `active` still there?

Comment: I want to remove all classes except `active` and `icon-`

Comment: The answer you selected won't do that. If an element has class `active` and a class you want to remove, it will just skip the element and not remove the other classes.

Comment: but others solution are breaking my list html layout.

Comment: MaX is correct, if that's required then my solution is not complete. You can however use `removeClass` with a callback instead of `removeAttr('class')`: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/.

Comment: But it doesn't do what you want. Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').find("*:not(.active):not([class^=icon-])")
    .removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').end();
```

Comment: Awesome, its is working. everyone else solution is breaking my UL li layout

Answer (score 1):

Use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').find("*").not(".active").removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').end();
```

Comment: this is breaking my html layout

Answer (score 1):

If you know which classes to remove you can use `removeClass('a_class another_class')` in stead of `removeAttr('class')`.

If you don't, you can use `each()` and cycle the classes added to the element, removing all but the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `not()` is the best option.

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu')
  .find("*")
  .not(".active, [class^='icon-']")
    .removeAttr('id')
    .removeAttr('class').end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu').find("*").not('.active, [class^="icon-"]')
                         .removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
```

Read `attribut start selectors` http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

And `not()` http://api.jquery.com/not